# Manipulate nth column of a .csv file with awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed, data-manipulation

I have a .csv file with 6 columns:

```
source  raised_time cleared_time    cause   pcause  sproblem
source1 rtime1  ctime1  cause1  communicationsSubsystemFailure#model.route.1.2  oMCIFailure#model.route.1.2
source2 rtime2  ctime2  cause2  equipmentMalfunction#model.route.1.2    deviceNotActive#model.route.1.2
```

I want to manipulate the 5th and 6th columns of the .csv file with below rules:

1. Convert the first letters of 5th and 6th columns to upper case
2. Keep the strings upto the character: "#" and remove the trailing part (which are coming after the # char)
3. Put a space between the lower case and upper case letters

So the wanted format is:

```
source  raised_time cleared_time    cause   pcause  sproblem
source1 rtime1  ctime1  cause1  Communication Subsystem Failure OMCI Failure
source2 rtime2  ctime2  cause2  Equipment Malfunction   Device Not Active
```

How can I do that with awk or sed command?

I tried to start with converting the first letter to upper case with the command:

```
awk 'BEGIN {$5 = toupper(substr($5,1,1))
    substr($5, 2)}1' input_file
```

but it did not work.

Comment: Your description would lead to the output `O M C I Failure`.  How do you want to deal with those (apparently) unwanted spaces.

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: @tripleee, I tried to start with converting the first letter to upper case with the command: "awk 'BEGIN {$5 = toupper(substr($5,1,1)) substr($5, 2)}1' input_file" but it did not work.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, Yes, you are correct. Maybe I should edit the rule like: Put a space between lower case and upper case letters.

Comment: If not now, later you will regret breaking up data that is meant to be in one column, with an unknowable 0-n spaces for any column. I'd recommend converting to `Equipment_Malfunction` (with an underscore, instead of a space). Store you data in that format, if you have fussy users that don't understand underscores, then `sed 's/_/ /g' file > report_version.txt` will give them what they want in their report, and you will still have a regular data set, ie. `$1,$2,$3,$4,$5`.  Good luck.

Comment: `I have a .csv file with 5 columns:` but the sample you gave seems to have 6 columns and not to be a csv (comma separated values).

Comment: The problem with your attempt is that `BEGIN` only gets executed once, before there is any input. Just take out the `BEGIN` label to wnconditionally execute your action on every input line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said your input is CSV (Comma-Separated Values) but there's are no commas in it while it does have apparently random spacing between fields so I assume you actually meant TSV (Tab-Separated Values). If so then this should do what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR > 1 {
    for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) {
        new = ""
        old = $i
        sub(/#.*/,"",old)
        while ( match(old,/[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+/) ) {
            new = new substr(old,1,RSTART-1) " " substr(old,RSTART,RLENGTH)
            old = substr(old,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        }
        new = new old
        $i = toupper(substr(new,1,1)) substr(new,2)
    }
}
{ print }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
source  raised_time     cleared_time    cause   pcause  sproblem
source1 rtime1  ctime1  cause1  Communications Subsystem Failure        OMCI Failure
source2 rtime2  ctime2  cause2  Equipment Malfunction   Device Not Active
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works fine and is very straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

A GNU `sed` implementation, assuming input file format is tsv (tab separated values):

```
sed -E '1! {
s/\t/\n/4
h
s/[^\n]*//
s/#[^\t]*//g
s/\B[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]/ &/g
s/\b[[:lower:]]/\U&/g
H
g
s/\n.*\n/\t/
}' file.tsv
```

If fields are separated by `,` then just replace the `\t` with the `,`.
If fields are separated by non-blank to blank transition then put `s/^\s+//; s/\s+$//; s/\s+/\t/g` at the beginning of the `sed` expression.

Comment: Thank you. This also works fine but I think I will use the awk method since it is easier to understand.